# Can I use groovy templating instead of scala for Play 2.0 based Java applications?

Tags: scala, jakarta-ee, groovy, playframework, playframework-2.0

I am new Play 2.0, I am having hard time understanding scala templating for creating views.
Can I switch back to groovy as it existed in earlier versions of Play framework. for e.g: Play 1.2, Play 1.2.4

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, there is a module available for groovy:
https://github.com/manuelbernhardt/play2-groovy-templates

I've found the Scala templates not too bad to work with after a week of playing with them--especially if you're using Scala on the controller part. You might consider sticking it out for the learning curve.

**Adding for the comments:**

```
object ApplicationBuild extends Build {

...

    val appDependencies = Seq(
      "eu.delving" %% "groovy-templates-plugin" % "1.1"
    )

    val main = PlayProject(appName, appVersion, appDependencies, mainLang = SCALA).settings(
      resolvers += "Delving Snapshot Repository" at "http://development.delving.org:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots",
      resolvers += "Delving Releases Repository" at "http://development.delving.org:8081/nexus/content/groups/public"
    )

}
```

Worked for me.

Comment: I added the resolvers as:resolvers += "Delving Releases Repository" at "http://development.delving.org:8081/nexus/content/groups/public"

resolvers += "Delving Snapshot Repository" at "http://development.delving.org:8081/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots"in plugins.sbt

Comment: Then I added  "eu.delving" %% "groovy-templates-plugin" % "1.1" in build.scala. But I am getting "COULDN'T COMPUTE DEPENDENCIES" message. Where did I go wrong ?

Comment: I just added it all in Build.scala (posted it in the answer)

Comment: Thanks it worked. I am sorry here is an un-related question, I am getting this error with my routes file - "Cannot use a method returning Unit as an Handler". what could be psossible reason ?

Comment: Can you post the context of the error? Maybe in a new question?

Comment: Maybe it's complaining that you're not calling the template rendering part at the end of the controller function?