# "Cannot use a method returning Unit as an Handler" getting this error in routes file - Play 2.0 Framework

Tags: jakarta-ee, routes, playframework-2.0

I have these 2 methods in my contoller:

```
public static void index() {
   List<Tweet> tweets = Tweet.findLatest();
   render(Template("index.html").params(tweets).render());
}


public static void create(String tweet) {
   Tweet t = new Tweet();
   t.tweet = tweet;
   t.save();
   render(Template("index.html").params(t).render());
}
```

Now the routes is shouting at me saying "Cannot use a method returning Unit as an Handler". My route file has this default route defined in it:

`GET     /                           controllers.Application.index()`

what could be the possible reason ?

Answer (score 11):

Raul, each action of the controller is expected to be static and to return Result

```
public static Result index() {
      List<Tweet> tweets = Tweet.findLatest();
      return ok(Template("index.html").params(tweets).render());
}
```

Comment: With the groovy view template plugin the syntax is a bit different. Of course, he didn't mention he was using that plugin anywhere, so I can see why you wouldn't have known that. I answered his other question, so I knew: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10201130/can-i-use-groovy-templating-instead-of-scala-for-play-2-0-based-java-application

Comment: Wes, but action still should return Result, could you edit my post in part of groovy ? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think it's supposed to be like so:

```
...
return ok(
  Template("index.html").params(tweets).render()
);

...

return ok(
  Template("index.html").params(t).render()
);
...
```